# Word 365 crashes when I try to run a macro, or view a list of macros in a document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a large document that has several dozen macros, and buttons to invoke those macros.  Some time in the last several weeks when I try to run any of those macros or View->Macros, Word crashes.

I renamed the Normal.docm file as DefectiveNormal.docm to see if this file is the problem.  No change.

From the event log:

- EventData
  AppName WINWORD.EXE
  AppVersion  16.0.16626.20170
  AppTimeStamp    64cc5d7a
  ModuleName  VBE7.DLL
  ModuleVersion   0.0.0.0
  ModuleTimeStamp 63e1cbeb
  ExceptionCode   c0000005
  FaultingOffset  00000000002c623a
  ProcessId   0x26e8
  ProcessCreationTime 0x1d9ccb21829fe6d
  AppPath C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE
  ModulePath  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\VBE7.DLL
  IntegratorReportId  a0f686fa-3f8f-4e4c-81a7-4eb84d491aea
  PackageFullName
  PackageRelativeAppId

I reinstalled Office, opened in safe mode, opened my document, and it saw no macros, of course, but it allowed me to record a macro.  I saved the document and then reopened in normal mode.  View macros still crashes it.  It does not appear that reinstall created a new Normal.docm.

I saved the file as an RTF, then reopened Word, opened the RTF and the macro command crashes Word.

A backup from last year that worked has the same behavior.

I expected to either run a macro or open a list of macros.

Comment: Difficult for us to suggest anything here -seems like either your files or your Office install are corrupted, or you have some other software installed on your computer which is causing the problem.

Comment: Would you try recording and running a macro (doesn't matter when the macro does ...) using Excel ... and/or any other VBA-enabled application you have (PowerPoint, Access etc) and see if you have the same problem as you do in Word.

Comment: Just to be sure, you do mean Normal.dotm, not Normal.docm?

Comment: This is a Word installation problem, not a programming issue. You'll get better answers at http://answers.microsoft.com or at Super User